# enter data into a search field while web scraping in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I would like to find the elevations of multiple data points using this website: http://mygeoposition.com/.  It has one search field where latitude and longitude can be entered; you then press enter and the altitude pops up on the map.

I have a data set with about 2000 coordinates, and my question was how to use R to automate this task.  I can do basic webscraping, such as downloading tables using the XML package.  I'm just not sure how to writes a program that enters the coordinates into the field and then submits the query.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the Google elevation API?

I maintain a package called `rgbif` for the GBIF API http://www.gbif.org/developer/summary

In there I have a function `elevation()`. It's somewhat flexible in the inputs it takes. Some examples are in a gist at :

https://gist.github.com/sckott/2d3ae5f0cecca3deb436

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know if you run into any problems with it